# How to run Python script in VS Code with an extension Code Runner?

Tags: python

I installed Code Runner extension in VS Code. In my `settings.json` I have set `"python.pythonPath": "python"` option and python is in my Win10 PATH variable.

In `code-runner.executorMap` option in settings.json python is set by `"python": "python.pythonPath"`. However, when I run my script with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> I get

```
'python.pythonPath' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

If I set in `code-runner.executorMap` python option to absolute path like `"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\python.exe"` I get complaining about whitespaces

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Only the first word is taken, until the first whitespace occur. If I put `\` to escape whitespace I get JSON error.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it. Simple, in settings.json in `"code-runner.executorMap"` under python option put

```
"python": "python"
```

and now it searches python in Win10 PATH and runs by clicking run icon or ctrl-alt-N.